# .net durable resource manager for transactional filesystem access

Tags: c#, .net, ntfs, system.transactions, txf

I'm trying to wrap my head around the use of the System.Transactions namespace in C#. I've found some documentation on MSDN regarding using resource managers,  but it only covers volatile, in-memory resource managers in any detail (like Transactional ). I'm basically looking for something that I can use inside of a TransactionScope, just like Transactional<> but use it for writing/modifying/deleting files on disk. Does something like this exist in the standard libs? I've read that NTFS has "TxF" now to allow transactional filesystem access - I was expecting to find something in .net that leverages that. Perhaps I need to implement my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx) or is this not what you are looking for?

Bart de Smet also has [an article](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/05/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Introducing-TxF-in-C_2300_-_2800_part-1_2900_-_2D00_-Transacted-file-delete.aspx) about this on his blog.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to implement it on your own. But see following to get started:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/KTM.aspx
- [Windows Vista - Introducing TxF in C# (part 2) - Using System.Transactions and the DTC](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/19/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Introducing-TxF-in-C_2300_-_2800_part-2_2900_-_2D00_-Using-System.Transactions-and-the-DTC.aspx)
- [NTFS: Enhance Your Apps With File System Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx)